# saveChangesAsync update object I didn't save it

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, save, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using entity framework core to get an object from the database this object I will use it to create another object, so my steps was

1- get object form database

2- change a property in this object

3- use this object to add another object of another type to database

4- call

```
  await _context.AppLogs.AddAsync(log);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

after that EF add my object "log" and automatically update my first object property in the database

I want to ask if that valid, and why as I didn't call update function I just change a property!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF will automatically detect changes made to an existing entity that is tracked by the context. The entity is tracked when you load/query from the database . So that simply modify the values assigned to properties and then call `SaveChanges` will automatically update the database :

```
var blog = context.Blogs.First();
blog.Url = "http://sample.com/blog";
context.SaveChanges();
```

If you don't want to update database for the entity , you can set entity state to `Unchanged`:

```
var blog = context.Blogs.First();
blog.Url = "http://sample.com/blog";
context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Unchanged; 
context.SaveChanges();
```

Unchanged entities are not touched by `SaveChanges`. Updates are not sent to the database for entities in the Unchanged state.